# For Loop in Kendo Grid Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've a big trouble with Kendo Grid.

If I use a for loop as client template as this

```
col.Bound(m => m.Compteurs)
    .ClientTemplate("# for (var i=0;i<4;i++) { console.log(i) } #");
```

i is never incremented.
Same with while loop and increment inside loop.

how to resolve this ?

Thank you

EDIT - Full declaration of Grid :

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<EAGLE.Models.ParamUf>()
.Name("ParamGrid")
.Columns(col =>
    {
        col.Bound(m => m.Groupement);
        col.Bound(m => m.Etablissement).ClientTemplate("#= Etablissement.EtablissementName #");
        col.Bound(m => m.Service).ClientTemplate("#= Service.ServiceName #");
        col.Bound(m => m.Discipline).ClientTemplate("#= Discipline.DisciplineName #");
        col.Bound(m => m.Unite).ClientTemplate("#= Unite.UniteName #");
        col.Bound(m => m).ClientTemplate(Html.Partial("_Tel").ToHtmlString());
        col.Bound(m => m.Unite.TypeHebergement).Title("Hébergement");
        col.Bound(m => m.Installe);
        col.Bound(m => m.Ferme);
        col.Bound(m => m.Compteurs).ClientTemplate("# for (var i=0;i<4;i++) { console.log(i) } #");        
        col.Command(commands =>
        {
            commands.Edit().UpdateText("Mettre à jour").CancelText("Annuler").Text("Edit");
            commands.Destroy().Text("Suppr.");
        }).Title(string.Empty).Width(160);

    }
)
.DataSource(data => data
                .Ajax()
                .Read(read => read.Action("Param_Read", "Param", new { entityCode = @ViewBag.Code, entityType = @ViewBag.Type }).Data("filterUnit"))
                    .Model(m => 
                    {
                        m.Id(a => a.Unite.UniteCode);
                        m.Field(a => a.Etablissement).DefaultValue(new EAGLE.Models.Etablissement());
                        m.Field(a => a.Service).DefaultValue(new EAGLE.Models.Service());
                        m.Field(a => a.Discipline).DefaultValue(new EAGLE.Models.Discipline());
                        m.Field(a => a.Unite).DefaultValue(new EAGLE.Models.Unite());
                    }) 
                .Create(cre => cre.Action("Param_Create", "Param"))
                .Update(upd => upd.Action("Param_Update", "Param"))
                .Destroy(des => des.Action("Param_Destroy", "Param"))
                .Batch(false)
                .ServerOperation(false))
.Pageable(pager => pager
    .Enabled(false)        
    .Messages(m => m.Display("Nombre total d'hébergement : {2}"))
    .Messages(m => m.Empty("Pas d'hébergement."))
    .PreviousNext(false)
    .Input(false)
    .Numeric(false))   
.ToolBar(toolbar => { toolbar.Create(); })
.Editable(ed => ed.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("_ParamEdit"))
.Events(e => e.DataBound("onDatabound"))
)
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have the **complete opposite** problem where the counter will not **stop** incrementing (even with a hard coded less than number as you have here) and it will crash the tab. Nothing wrong with the JavaScript syntax as it will run perfectly in dev tools.

Comment: Yes, we have found that the generated code remove the ++ . I post the answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the next that have this issue, you can resolve by different way.

1st way (tricky) :
Add javascript function `increment`

```
function increment(a) 
{
   return a++;
}
```

And use it in template

```
col.Bound(m => m.Compteurs)
    .ClientTemplate("# for (var i=0;i<4;increment(i)) { console.log(i) } #");
```

2nd way by c# code (include this between col.Bound) :

```
    int i = 0;
    foreach (EAGLE.Models.Compteur c in ViewBag.Compteurs)
    {
        col.Bound(m => m.Compteurs[i].Dispo).Title(c.NomCourt)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = String.Format("background-color:\\#{0}", c.Color), @class = "compteur" })
            .HeaderTemplate("<img class='iconeHeader' src='data:image/png;base64," + c.Picto + "' title='"+ c.Nom +"' />");
        i++;
    }
```

3rd way (Matthew's Answer) :

```
 var template = "# for (var i=0;i<4;i++) { console.log(i) } #";
 var plusEncoded= System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("+"); 
 template = Regex.Replace(template, @"[+]", plusEncoded);
 col.Bound(m => m.Compteurs).ClientTemplate(template);
```

Comment: return ++a would be better, it doesn't really matter in your example, but still...

Comment: You could put the entire for-loop inside a javascript function. That would be a lot cleaner.

Comment: the third way doesn't work. This does however: 
var template = "# for (var i=0;i<4;i++) { console.log(i) } #";
var plusEncoded= System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("+");
template = Regex.Replace(template, @"[+]", plusEncoded);
... col.Bound(m => m.Compteurs).ClientTemplate(template);

Comment: I have updated the answer with your snippet. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It seems + or ++ are removed when used in Partial views with Kendo controls. 
There is another workaround for this issue:

```
col.Bound(m => m.Compteurs)
    .ClientTemplate("# for (var i = 4; i > 0; i--) { console.log(i) } #");
```

hope this helps

Comment: This helps me since I had partial view and had no way why looping not working until got this answer. You saved my day! Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

This should have worked. At least this JavaScript version does [work](http://jsbin.com/ahagit/1/edit):

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: [
    { name: "John" },
    { name: "Jane" }
  ],
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "name", 
     template: "# for (var i=0;i<4;i++) { console.log(i) } #" 
    }
  ]
});
```

Could it be that your grid isn't ajax bound? Showing the complete configuration would confirm or deny this.

Comment: The grid is ajax bound with DataSource Object. Another columns works well with ClientTemplate or ClientTemplate + Partial View. I'm using Kendo MVC Component for .Net to generate this.